# PDF to Text Creation with PDF Box: No able to get formatting information

Tags: java, text, converters, pdfbox

I am using PDFBox to convert pdf file into txt file.  I am getting text from PDF file.

```
try {
            parser.parse();
            cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
            pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
            pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
            parsedText = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
            writePDFFileToTextFile(parsedText, textFilePath);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //System.out.println("An exception occured in parsing the PDF Document.");
            log.error(e.toString());
            textFilePath = null;
        } finally {
            try {
                if (cosDoc != null) {
                    cosDoc.close();
                }
                if (pdDoc != null) {
                    pdDoc.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                log.error(ex.toString());
            }
        }
```

But i want formatting related information also like bold,italic,font size,paragraph etc.

Can i get these information with PDFBox?
If not..then which API should I use?

Comment: A '.txt' file does not include *any* of the information you list, just ..text.  You might try converting it to `.rtf` or `.html` instead, both of which support **formatted** text.